# Facebook Graph API calls not retrieving all fields

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm requesting my `me/albums` with:

```
  new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/albums",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                parseAlbumResponse(response);
            }
        }).executeAsync();
```

Problem is that the response object only contains 3 fields:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "...",
      "name": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
...
```

Instead of all fields documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/album/). Sames goes for `/{album-id}/photos`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
...
```

Instead of [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/album/photos).
It was working last time I've checked but all of a sudden this strange behaviour happened.
I've tested with [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and the result it's the same so I guess it's not a problem from my app.

I'm using `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`.
Did Facebook changed something in the requests parameters?

**EDIT:**
As user **luschn** suggested:

> Declarative Fields
>
> To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in
>   v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for
>   your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes
>   likes and comments by default, but GET
>   /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more
>   details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

So I had to change my requests to:
Web console:
`me/albums?fields=name, cover_photo, count` and `/{album-id}/photos?fields=id, images`

Java:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id, images");

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "name, cover_photo, count");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog, you have to specify the fields you want to get returned.

Comment: Thanks, let me do some changes and I will get back at you.